# How can I subtract to each column its mean using awk?

Tags: awk, mean

I have a file such as the following (but with thousands of rows and hundreds of columns)

```
1 2 1
1 2 2
3 2 3
3 2 6
```

How can I subtract to each column/field its mean using awk, in order to obtain such a thing?

```
-1 0 -2
-1 0 -1
 1 0  0
 1 0  3
```

Thank you very much for your help.

The most close solution http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/102293-normalize-dataset-awk.html does not seem to do the job "element by element". Of course it performs another operation, but the generic concept is *"perform an operation on each column using a value calculated on that column"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk` in two passes:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[i]+=$i
    }
    next
} 
{
    for (y=1;y<=NF;y++) {
        printf "%2d ", $y-=(a[y]/(NR-FNR)) 
    }
    print "" 
}' file file
```

With `awk` in one pass:

```
awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[i]+=$i; 
        b[NR,i]=$i
    }
} 
END {
    for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) { 
        for (j=1;j<=NF;j++) {
            printf "%2d ",b[i,j]-=(a[j]/NR)
        }
        print ""
    } 
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.  Is there a method to do it automatically on _"NF"_ columns?

Comment: @leonardvertighel Updated the solution to be generic.

Comment: Thank you very much! I took a minute to figure out why two times the same input file and why I had a lot of zeros: it was the format "%2d " to be changed to  "%2f " for my needs.

Comment: @leonardvertighel The reason for two input files is because we are doing this in two passes. The first pass we will capture the total for each column and then in second pass we will subtract the mean from each column value. Yes, thats the beauty with `printf`. You can customize the formatting of your output. :)

Comment: @leonardvertighel I have added an alternate solution to do the same in one pass.

Comment: Thanks. Barely counting the blinking of the cursor :-) it seems that the first solution is slightly faster (3 blinks against 4 for 50 columns and 26.000 rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, numpy as np
a = np.array([i.strip().split() for i in open(sys.argv[1])],dtype =float)
for i in a - np.mean(a,axis=0): print ' '.join(map(str, i))
```

Usage : python script.py inputFile